# How to extract a specific value from the linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

I am building a NET 5 API and am unable to extract and calculate something. I have a table StockTransaction which among other has property Quantity (I skipped some properties for brevity):

```
public class StockTransaction : BaseEntity
{      
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public bool Purchase { get; set; }
    public int Resolved { get; set; }       
}
```

Suppose I have 7 transactions, all of which are purchase:

```
List<StockTransaction> list = new List<StockTransaction>
{
new StockTransaction {Id = 1, Purchase = true, Quantity = 10, Resolved = 5, Price = 50},
new StockTransaction {Id = 2, Purchase = true, Quantity = 5, Resolved = 5, Price = 70},
new StockTransaction {Id = 3, Purchase = true, Quantity = 8, Resolved = 8, Price = 25},
new StockTransaction {Id = 4, Purchase = true, Quantity = 7, Resolved = 5, Price = 77},
new StockTransaction {Id = 5, Purchase = true, Quantity = 1, Resolved = 1, Price = 23},
new StockTransaction {Id = 6, Purchase = true, Quantity = 3, Resolved = 0, Price = 14},
new StockTransaction {Id = 7, Purchase = true, Quantity = 2, Resolved = 0, Price = 17},           
};
```

And I would like to get the value of the last 7 quantities, which in this case gives 176 ((2 x 17) + (3 x 14) + (1 x 23) + (1 x 77)). (How) can this be done? Every help and hint is more then appreciated...

Comment: This should get you started: `list .Select(s => s.Quantity * s.Price).Sum();`

Comment: I assume you know the `Select()` statement. It's not really clear what keeps you from getting the results you want.

Comment: Thanks, I know that part, the problem is in extracting the value of only some quantities...

Comment: ` (3 x 14) + (1 + 23)` why is the third parenthis an addition?

Comment: I made a mistake while typing...

Comment: You can use aggregate function in linq for such things

Comment: By last 7 you mean recent 7 transactions? So I am assuming you are taking date_created in base entity?

Comment: no, just quantities, those are the last 4 transactions (the last one should fetch only 1 quantity out of 7 and give the value of 77)

Comment: I skipped datecreated for brevity, it's in the StockTransactions, the baseentity holds only id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you have tagged your question with LINQ, do it with a normal loop:

```
private static decimal SumOfLastTransaction(IEnumerable<StockTransaction> stockTransactions, int max)
    {
        decimal result = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        foreach(var stockTransaction in stockTransactions.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id))
        {
            
            if(sum + stockTransaction.Quantity <= max)
            {
                result += stockTransaction.Quantity * stockTransaction.Price;
                sum += stockTransaction.Quantity;
            }
            else
            {
                result += (max - sum) * stockTransaction.Price;
                return result;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

You loop over the last items in your list. You sum the amount of transactions and check whether it is smaller than your maximum. As long as they are smaller, you can add the amount of transactions. If not, you check how much is missing until your maximum is reached and substract this from your quantity.

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9oM4pj

Comment: this is the best answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var last3=list.OrderByDescending(x=>x.CreatedDate).Take(3).Select(x=>x.Quantity * x.Price).Sum();

var requiredSum=last3+list.Where(x=>x.id==4).Select(x=>x.Price).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This is great start, but how to fetch the value of the fourth transaction and take only one quantity with the value of 77?

Comment: Ok modifying my answer

Comment: So you want values from 4th to 7 transaction only?

Comment: yes, but only one quantity from the fourth transaction, and the whole 5, 6, 7 transaction

Comment: you can use Skip and Take to acquire sub range of data and ElementAt to get specific records

Comment: `.Select(t => t.Price * (t.Id == 4 ? 1 : t.Quantity)).Sum()` - will satisfy OP's requirements ;)

Comment: ~Petar please check modified answer

Comment: thanks will try everything and let you know, thank you all so much!

Comment: I just had to rewrite a code a bit, used First() - list.Where(x=>x.Id==4).Select(x=>x.Price).First();

Comment: I don't know if this is what OP wanted. In his example, it might get the correct result, but if Transaction with Id = 5 had a quantity of 2 instead of 1, you would not need any item of the transaction with Id = 4. @PetarSardelic Maybe you should check my answer.

Comment: My answer also produces required result, the question was tagged with linq so I did it in linq way.

Comment: `int result = 176` also produces the required result, but only with the sample data from OP. With other data, your code will fail.

Comment: yes I agree, your answer was maybe better with regards to my question, but the answer I marked as the right one is more valuable from the point of real world problems and that is why I have chosen it, it might be more useful for others to see this answer as the right one...anyway, it was my mistake for formulating question that way, I just wanted to make things simplified. Mea culpae, thank you everybody for your efforts.